# CKEditor doesn't allow to have nested <a> element in widget

Tags: ckeditor

I would like to have widget that can have `<button><a></a></button>` inside. Unfortunately CKE deletes `<a></a>`. How to overcome this?

This is the code:

```
CKEDITOR.plugins.add( 'interButton', {
    requires: 'widget',
    icons: 'interButton',
    init: function( editor ) {

        editor.widgets.add('interButton', {
            button: 'Add Button',

            template:
                '<button><a></a></button>',

            allowedContent:
                'button[*]{*}(*); a[*]{*}(*)',

            upcast: function( element ) {
                return element.name == 'button';
            }
        });

    }
});
```

Comment: Do you really want to overcome valid HTML? Reference: https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/text-level-semantics.html#the-a-element

Comment: Could you please be more specific?

Comment: placing an anchor tag in a button isn't valid in HTML

Comment: Ok, you are right. I will change HTML to proper one.

Comment: Sometimes you got an inaccurate design agency where you can't debate about correct usage of HTML elements. You just have to implement the given. I wonder how you'd do that with ckeditor...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can push certain elements to the protectedSource and CKE will obey.

**example:**

```
config.protectedSource.push(/<button[^>]*><a[^>]*><\/a><\/button>/g);
```

I haven't tested the above, but it should work.